# Import Data from Excel to SQL Server DB using LINQ to Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel, linq, entity-framework

I'm newbie in Linq to SQL and I want to import an Excel file contents to my SQL server Database.

This is My Code :

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dbEntities = new BASUEntities();
        string pathToExcelFile = importFileName;
        var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);

        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.FirstName, "FName");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.LastName, "LName");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.NationalCode, "NatCode");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.EmploymentID, "EmpID");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.WorkUnit, "WorkUnit");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.JobOrdination, "JobOrd");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.Profession, "Profession");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.PostTitle, "PTitle");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.EmploymentType, "EmpType");
        excelFile.AddMapping<UserInfo>(x => x.PhoneNumber, "PhoneNo");

        excelFile.TrimSpaces = TrimSpacesType.Both;
        excelFile.ReadOnly = true;

        IQueryable<UserInfo> UserInfz = (from a in excelFile.Worksheet<UserInfo>()
            select a);

        foreach (UserInfo userInfo in UserInfz)
        {
            dbEntities.UserInfoes.Add(userInfo);
            dbEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
        LoadAllUsers(); //Load Users in DataGrid

    }
```

it worked for 55 rows and then i got this error :

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities.
>   See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

My excel file contains more than 700 rows.
I think it's a Memory problem!

How can i solve this?

Comment: what's the validation error message? I am pretty sure there is something wrong at row 56. something does not fit well with the model validation

Comment: @Aniket i tried deleting 56th row from excel, it continued to 200 but stuck there, and deleting rows isn't useful anymore...it just import 200 rows of excel.

Comment: afaik, the data seems to be corrupted. Openup something like beyond compare and see which row is allowed, and which row fails.

Answer (score 0):

Rows 56 and 200 generate a validation error because the data in those rows doesn't match the definition of `UserInfo`

The following code will tell you exactly what the issue with those rows is

```
foreach (UserInfo userInfo in UserInfz)
{
    dbEntities.UserInfoes.Add(userInfo);
    dbEntities.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Entity of type '{0}' in state '{1}' has the following validation errors:", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("- Property: '{0}', Error: '{1}'", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
    throw new Exception(sb.ToString(), ex);
}
```